# Create a dictionary consisting of items of subarrays and sublists

Tags: python, numpy, loops, dictionary, list-comprehension

The data

```
import numpy as np
class_data=[np.array(['class3','class5']),np.array(['claas1','class9'])]
data=[['dog.txt','cat.txt'],['mouse.txt','horse.txt']]
```

needed result is to create a dictionary that looks like that:

```
[[{'text': 'dog.txt', 'class': 'class3'},
  {'text': 'cat.txt', 'class': 'class5'}],
 [{'text': 'mouse.txt', 'class': 'class1'},
  {'text': 'horse.txt', 'class': 'class9'}]]
```

My attempt is:

```
out_data=[]
for kk,kb in zip(class_data,data):
    for ii,kb2 in enumerate(kb):
        for i,v in enumerate(kk):
            out_data.append({'text': kb2, 'class': v})
            
out_data
```

which does every possible combination from each corresponding array which is wrong.

```
[{'text': 'dog.txt', 'class': 'class3'},
 {'text': 'dog.txt', 'class': 'class5'},
 {'text': 'cat.txt', 'class': 'class3'},
 {'text': 'cat.txt', 'class': 'class5'},
 {'text': 'mouse.txt', 'class': 'claas1'},
 {'text': 'mouse.txt', 'class': 'class9'},
 {'text': 'horse.txt', 'class': 'claas1'},
 {'text': 'horse.txt', 'class': 'class9'}]
```

the solution should work iteratively and can work with larger datasets

Comment: the second block of code that says "needed result"

Comment: `for ((class1,class2),(text1,text2)) in zip(class_data,data): print(f'{{class:{class1},text:{text1}}}'); print(f'{{class:{class2},text:{text2}}}'); print('***')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
out_data=[]
for pairs in zip(data, class_data):
    temp_list = []
    for x in zip(pairs[0], pairs[1]):       
        temp_list.append({'text': x[0], 'class': x[1]})       
    out_data.append(temp_list)

out_data
```

Output:

```
[[{'text': 'dog.txt', 'class': 'class3'},
  {'text': 'cat.txt', 'class': 'class5'}],
 [{'text': 'mouse.txt', 'class': 'claas1'},
  {'text': 'horse.txt', 'class': 'class9'}]]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to iterate correspondly on 1 (or more) different data structures, I would recommend using zip, to retrieve them together. like this:

```
import numpy as np
class_data=[np.array(['class3','class5']),np.array(['class1','class9'])]
data=[['dog.txt','cat.txt'],['mouse.txt','horse.txt']]

out_data=[]
for c_d, d_d in zip(class_data,data):
    for c_d_i, d_d_i in zip(c_d,d_d):
        out_data.append({"text": d_d_i, "class":c_d_i})
print(out_data)
```

output recieved:

```
[{'text': 'dog.txt', 'class': 'class3'}, {'text': 'cat.txt', 'class': 'class5'}, {'text': 'mouse.txt', 'class': 'class1'}, {'text': 'horse.txt', 'class': 'class9'}]
```

Comment: Note that your output is included in only one list. Check the desired result in the question to see what is different.

Comment: true, haven't noticed. fixed. thanks

Comment: It is still different.

Comment: compared, and the outputs are exactly the same (expect enters which means nothing), where do tou see differences?

Comment: the second block of code in my question is what I am trying to do. I think you were looking at the last part of the question.